# How can I give Drop Shadow effect to a masked image in xd

Tags: layers, shapes, mask, effects, adobe-xd

I have a masked image, and I want to give a little drop shadow on it in **Abobe XD**.
But I am not able to do so. Can someone please tell suggest any idea...

reference image
[image]

This is what I have tried so far

- Tried giving the shape a drop shadow first and then masked it, but it did not work.

Comment: I do not have illustrator right now. Are you using a clipping path?

Comment: Dear @Rafael It is not Ai, I am trying to do this in Adobe Xd.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I did not know that app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicate the normal shape (the one with the shadow). Now apply the duplicate as the mask on an image. Move the masked image on top of the shape with the drop shadow. Select both pieces and group them.

Example

[image]